# How do I deal with an array with PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Lets pretend I've got some SQL and variables such as:

```
$number = 5;
```

And my PDO sql is:

```
SELECT * FROM things where ID = :number
```

Except, number is actually an array such as:

```
$number = array(1,2,3);
```

Which doesn't work out at all for

```
SELECT * FROM things where ID in ( :number )
```

How can I accomplish this with PDO?
Presently I'm looping through the array, type-casting to int, and injecting the string to the SQL before I do any PDO binding on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: I'm personally using a PDO wrapper which provides for `WHERE ID IN (??)` alternative syntax to pass arrays. But as workaround with standard functions you could often utilize the SQL function `FIND_IN_SET(id,:number)` and just pass the array as list in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common solution is to implode number (delimiting by a comma) and put the resulting string in to where in() without binding it as a param. Just be careful, you have to make sure it is safe for query, in this case.

Same thing here:
[Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to at least get rid of the loop, you can generate your string as such:

```
$numberArray = array(1,2,3);
$number = implode(",", $numberArray);

// $number is now the string "1,2,3"
```

Comment: Err, no. The loop is to sanitize my user input before SQL injection. I'm not about to implode an array without making sure someone didn't put bobby tables in it.

Comment: @Incognito: Doesn't PDO do that for you?

Comment: @Incognito:  Sanitizing is not mentioned in the question.  Someone reading the question as it is currently written might reasonably conclude, as I did, that either any necessary processing/validation had already happened during the generation of the array or else that sanitization is not necessary because the array is assigned as a series of integer values as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$foo = conection->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(:number)");

foreach ($number as $val) {
$foo->bindValue(':number', $val);
$foo->execute();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think running the query multiple times is the solution here.  The whole point of `IN` is to run 1 query for multiple items.

Answer (score -1):

You can't bind that variable directly into statement.

Do something like this:

```
<?php
    $number = array(1, 2, 3);
    $number = implode(', ', $number);

    // Bind it here...

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(:number);";
```

Comment: -1, this results in `SELECT ... id IN('1, 2, 3')`, which is certainly not going to work